# Python/Pandas: How to combine data from multiple rows into one based on two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to use pandas to organize my data in a dataframe.  The input looks like this:

```
Well   Target   Value  
1      X        12.5
1      Y        10.6
1      Z        10.2
2      X        12.8
2      Y        10.7
2      Z        10.0
3      X        12.9
3      Y        10.5
3      Z        10.1
```

I'm trying to make a single row for each well with the different targets as columns like this:

```
Well   X     Y     Z
1      12.5  10.6  10.2
2      12.8  10.7  10.0
3      12.9  10.5  10.1
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance.